# Tags are missing from my GitHub testing project

Tags: github, git-flow

I am working with GitFlow , i have updated tags which i can see in cmd but not able to see in GitHub page.

[GitHub Test Project link](https://github.com/yashfale/GitTestFlow/tree/master)

Screen grab of GitHub : 
[image]

Screen grab of cmd :

[image]

Am i missing something ? or need to do some parameter while adding tag .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you have created those tags locally on your machine, you will need to push these up to GitHub.  This can be done by running the command:

```
git push --tags
```

You can find more information about this [here](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Basics-Tagging) specifically in the Sharing Tags section.

> By default, the git push command doesn’t transfer tags to remote servers. You will have to explicitly push tags to a shared server after you have created them. This process is just like sharing remote branches